# How to automatically add a fixed tax in cart

Tags: cart, shipping, magento-1, tax, totals

I have been struggling to find a solution two days now... and it seems just impossible. All I want to do is to let the customer know about the shipping tax which is a fixed tax I've set ( flat rate, 19.84 RON ).

The thing is now.. every customer needs to go all the way to step 5 in the checkout page in order to see "wait, there's a shipping tax of 20RON ) which may or may not be unexpected for some.

I've been searching and looking on google for examples, but didn't manage to find anything for this case. I'm a starter with magento so I can't really "code" anything for it ..

I've made a cart rule for subtotal = 0 and subtotal >= 200 RON ( shipping tax = 0 ). So... I've thought there's a way to add the fixed rate right when the first product is added.

I'm not sure I explained it correctly but hopefully you understand what I want..

Comment: Did you tried event_observer?

Comment: I'd try it but.. as already said.. I have no idea how to code for Magento. I have found something on google yesterday about event observers but it was only working until 1.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that before an address is entered, no shipping cost calculation takes place, thus no shipping tax will be shown.

You will need to trigger the shipping cost calculation, i.e. the "totals collection" in the cart with a default address. Take a look at the free `AutoShipping` extension, developed for this purpose: https://github.com/integer-net/Autoshipping

Comment: Worked like a charm ! Thanks ... you saved me from hours and hours of head scratching !

Answer (score 2):

The only way to display a default shipping rate is to set the rate by default when the quote is created.

There used to be a module that did this on Magento Connect that did this but was unmaintained by its creator and was only certified up to Magento 1.1 CE. I have verified that this works up to 1.11 EE / 1.6 CE.

How it works

When a product is added to the cart (presumably on the first cart add) it checks its own module defaults for a sample destination shipping address. This can be configured via System > Config > Autoquote.

It uses this default address along with the specified default shipping method (defined in the config.xml) to specify and add the shipping method to the quote.

If you do not wish to use the module, the above description should be enough for you to bootstrap your own development.

Module is available here:

https://github.com/philwinkle/Mage_Autoquote

Cheers!

Comment: Check the accepted answer. The AutoShipping module works like a charm on 1.9.1.0